# Javascript classes define attribute in constructor or outside the class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I am creating a project that defines the following class:

```
class BankAccount {
 constructor(balance=0){
   this.balance = balance;
 }

 withdraw(amount){
    if(this.balance - amount >= BankAccount.overdraftlimit){
      this.balance -= amount;
    }
  }
}

BankAccount.overdraftlimit = -500;
```

My question here is about the definition of the property **overdraftlimit**

Is this the best way to define let's call a global property?
Or should be better to define it inside the `constructor` like

```
this.overdraftlimit = -500;
```

Thank you!!

Comment: that depends on your domain. can different bank account have different `overdraftlimit`? should a bank account be able to mutate it?

Comment: thanks for responding. No, another bank account cannot mutate it, and there will be different bank accounts with different overdraftlimits

Comment: if the overdraftlimit is not part of any specific instance, then it make sense to be defined as part of the class itself. otherwise make that part of your instance state.

Comment: I personaly would set this property in the constructor with a default value and create setter and getter for it

Comment: ok, so I understand that if it is defined as part of the class is independant of the instance and any instance can not mutate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `overdraftlimit` is shared across all the `BankAccount`, then go with the static propriety.

```
BankAccount.overdraftlimit = -500;
```

If every `BankAccount` have their own `overdraftlimit`, it should not be part of the class, but part of the single instances.

```
 constructor(balance = 0){
   this.balance = balance;
   this.overdraftlimit = -500;
 }
```

this way you could also change `overdraftlimit` without affecting other `BankAccount`.

Comment: ohhh, ok I got it. Declare it as a static property makes that this property can be shared by all the instances. If one change it, it will affect the other instances. As you was saying part of the class not of the instance. That is what you mean right?
Great explanation

Comment: yeah, that's it